# How to enable core PHP extension in Linux?

Tags: linux, lamp, php

I'm trying to understand the process for enabling an a core extension (dom) in php.  When I run phpinfo, I see '--disable-dom' in the configure command.  Am I supposed to re-install PHP?

Comment: How are you installing PHP?  Through a package manager?  From source?

Comment: That's a good question- I'm working off of an Amazon EC2 Fedora server instance that already had Apache-PHP installed.  How would I be able to tell how it was installed?

Comment: OK let me revise this- It's PHP as an Apache module- does that make a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What linux version are you using? If you are using Centos, you can install dom with command:

```
yum install php5-dom
```

Comment: Thanks Neto- tried that, seemed like a good option- but getting "No package php5-dom available"

Comment: Ok, this worked: "yum install php-dom" 
Thanks Neto, for the easiest path!

Answer (score 0):

The configure command only shows which options have been built directly into the PHP executable. It is still possible to provide extensions as... extensions, installable/buildable separately.

Comment: Ignacio- so how would I go about providing extensions separately?

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting apache. I think for Fedora it's `service httpd restart`

Answer (score 0):

centos/redhat is

```
yum install php-xml
```

As you can see here

```
# rpm -qf /etc/php.d/dom.ini
php-xml-5.2.9-2
```

Comment: Yeah, I did this "yum install php-dom" and I think it installed the php-xml as well- maybe points to the same thing?